# Use Java code from a Node.js server

Tags: java, node.js

I have a heavy Java application that does some calculations. I want my Node.js application to use that application. How can I do this?

Comment: **MAGIC** powers.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)so that we can help.

Comment: Node.js can not execute Java code, but there are plenty of inter-process communication solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can expose the Java calculation as a web service and make an Ajax call to it.

Comment: I thought there might be a library that makes this easier, for example, automatically converts Java functions to web services,  automatically converts the output of web services to Node objects, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need nodejs [addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)

Comment: This is what I meant. Unfortunately, it seems there are addons only for C and C++, not for Java.

Comment: Addon is a pattern I think. They've just explained how to wrap C++ but it should be possible for Java too.. There is [some info](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+v8+javascript+engine&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) on using V8 engine in Java, but it is not a ready made solution yet...